# Extract only the value (not the named value) of a field from any identified row of a dataframe

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am learning pySpark and have a question which I think is a fundamental one yet I am unable to crack it ..

Let's assume I have the following code

```
lettersDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('A',), ('B',), ('C',), ('D',), ('E', )], ['word'])
```

now I want to print 3rd row of the column 'word'

```
print lettersDF.head(3)[2] 
Row(word=u'C')
```

I just want to print 'C'.. how do I do it? I do not want this "dict" output, rather I want a "list" like output

Can someone please explain the how head(), tail(), take() and first() or similar "Action" keywords work? Somehow I think I am missing something fundamental

Comment: you can check the api: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.head

Comment: I have checked those.. trying to understand why would I get an output such as - > Row(word=u'C') rather than only 'C'

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it comes as a Row object (pyspark.sql.types.Row), you can convert it

```
print lettersDF.head(3)[2].asDict()
{'word': u'C'}
```